# Borre un elemento de la paleta de java

Tags: java

Borre sin querer un elemnto de la paleta, de la parte "components" en java, creo que fue un JTextField, y nose como volver a ponerlo. Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que vuelva a aparecer el JTextField en la paleta!?

[image]

Comment: Ya intentaste con `WIndow` -> `Reset window`?

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, y sigue sin aparecer.

Comment: click derecho en la paleta -> `Palette Manager` -> `Reset Palette`

Comment: Hice clic derecho en la paleta y habia una opcion que decia "Restore default palette...", mil gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, me imagino lo preocupante que debe de ser, es un control que se utiliza tanto jaja

Comment: ¿Lo resolviste con las indicaciones de @Alexander? Si es así sugiero que él escriba una respuesta con el procedimiento, para que la pregunta no quede abierta y pueda servir a futuros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema. También sería bueno que pongas una etiqueta a la pregunta con el IDE en cuestión... parece ser [tag:eclipse].

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans: 
Click derecho en la paleta -> `Palette Manager` -> `Reset Palette`
Eclipse:
Click derecho en la paleta -> `Restore default palette`